# Wrong xpath with Selenium says true with isDisplayed()

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am searching elements in a webpage using Selenium. I am using a wrapper class and wrapper methods over `findElement()` and passing keys to the wrapper using an xml. So, far this has worked well. Recently, I had to find a number of elements with similar className, and different xpaths in different settings. I tried creating a custom xpath using the className, and tried identifying the elements using a particular attribute which was different. The page structure looks something like :

```
<span class="app-icon">
<img class="app-icon-large" alt="WorkForce1" src="https://someWebAddress"/>
</span>
```

The xpath I used was:

```
workXPATH = .//span[1]/img[@alt="Workforce1"]
```

The problem is, if I replace `Workforce1` with some random word like `zenith`
the `isDisplayed()` method still returns true. And there is no possibility for zenith to be present in the dom structure. This is making me scratch my head. Does anyone have any idea why this is working in such a way?
The code is :

```
element.get("workXPATH").isDisplayed()
```

Comment: Check the correctness of provided examples as there are couple typos: `[@alt="Workforce1]` - incorrect, `[@alt="Workforce1"]` - correct, `"Workforce1" != "WorkForce1"`... Also explain what this `element.get("workXPATH).isDisplayed()` should do

Comment: Try using:  `driver.findelement(By.xpath("//span/img[@alt="WorkForce1"]")).isDisplayed()`

Comment: @Andersson : element is a class with get() method. The code for finding elements --- driver.findElement().. ---- is written inside the get() method

Comment: Share code for class `element` and `get()` method

Comment: I found the bug in my code. I had a wrapper which would continue the execution to the subsequent methods if a null value is returned. Sorry, it was quite naive of me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way.

**Explanation:** First get the String of `workForce1` image, using `alt` attribute.

Now Find WebElement using `xpath` locator. 
Then compare the `String` and `WebElement` using if condition.

```
String workForce1_text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span/img[@alt='WorkForce1']")).getAttribute("alt");
System.out.println(workForce1_text);

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span/img[@alt='WorkForce1']"));     
if(element.getAttribute("alt").contentEquals(workForce1_text))
{
    /*your action goes here.*/
}
```

Comment: If it's resolved your query, then please do accept the answer. Because it will help for other users as well :)

Answer (score 0):

IsDisplayed() Return True

This is because the (XPath) found in your HTML source code.

so the valid 
e.g.

```
WebElement Image = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='registrationForm']/div[13]/span/img")); // here you need to find unique value for your xpath if that repeated in the source
```

so : 
Image.get means nothing

also if you need to return the value from html attribute

```
Image.getAttribute("alt").equals("your expected results");
```